# How does an output current splits between two loads?

Tags: current, output

In this project a buck-boost IC outputs 5V @ 1.8A MAX. That OUTPUT can power two things simultaneously:

1. Charging a device through USB port
2. Power the project's control board

How can I be sure that the charging device doesn't take all the current for himself leaving the control board without current?

Maybe it's a banal question but I can't understand yet how two loads share a common current in this case. If a smartphone would draw 1.5A the control board won't run correctly as it needs 500mA. The fact is that, actually, seems to me that different devices might want to draw current at different speeds.

Here's the circuit
[image]

Thank you

Comment: There could indeed be an issue here - but it's also worth determining what the actual current draw is.  500 mA for example is a such a nice round number, it sounds like it was copied from the specs of an onboard regulator and may have little meaning in practice.  As for the smartphone/tablet, what current it draws likely depends on if it sees charger signalling resistors to indicate it can take more than 500 mA, or if it is one of the (relatively few) that will go ahead and try even without seeing that.

Comment: Also consider that the current upstream of the buck boost is necessarily higher than that downstream due to conservation of energy and efficiency losses.  Then look at what happens if the system is overloaded - will the voltage sag and current draw be reduced, will something shut down protectively, or will a damaging/dangerous situation result?

Comment: Thank you Chris. 500 mA is the maximum current draw value rounded a little bit by excess; just to be sure. I measured it on the previous version of board prototype. The story about data resistors is a bit confused, because today I understood how Apple devices actually behave and why, but I tested a Samsung smartphone on a boost board "ok for 1 A with Apple" and it charges at 0.5 A.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't think of it as the supply current to be shared between the loads.

Think of each load taking what it needs from the supply, which must then supply the sum of the currents.

Consider your banal question. If you had one load taking 500mA, and one load taking 1.5A, then they will need a supply capable of 2A output to power them correctly.

If the supply can only supply 1.8A, then the system will not work properly.

Exactly how improperly will depend on the detail of how the supply output voltage sags, and how the devices take less current as their input voltage drops.

If each load was a plain resistor, you could predict what would happen.

With a smartphone and a control board, complicated devices with DC-DC converters and power supply protection devices, it might stop taking current when the supply fell below 4.9v, it might take more to maintain the power, either might be possible, depending on what the designer has chosen to make it do.

Rule. The power supply must be able to supply the total current of all the loads that will connected at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

It is divided inversely proportional to the resistance of the loads. Effectively you have two resistors in parallel.
The problem here is that your loads are not pure ohms devices. Resistance of each is dependent of voltage, so it is hard to tell which ratio it will be in the end.